# Calling webassembly gc functions in c using emscripten/llvm

Tags: llvm, webassembly, emscripten

I am porting a library that uses libgc's garbage collected allocation to web using the emscripten/LLVM toolchain. I am aware that webassembly has MVP gc support. My idea is to redefine `GC_MALLOC` (the garbage collected allocation function from `libgc`) to be  `array.new` (the garbage collected version of allocation in `webassembly`). However, this does not seem possible as both llvm and c won't let me call `array.new` as there is a dot in the name.

How should I call native webassembly from LLVM IR that returns a gc allocated memory?

Reference to WebAssembly GC:

1. [API] https://github.com/WebAssembly/gc/blob/main/proposals/gc/MVP.md
2. [Talk on GC] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDNXomIn53Y